# GroupBy with multiple conditions running very slowly

Tags: performance-tuning

I have a list `lst` matching the pattern `{{_String, _String, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}..}`.  The outer list has about 150,000 elements (inner lists), so it is certainly not very long.  When I run:

```
lst // GroupBy[(#[[2]] &) -> (Drop[#, {2}] &)] // Map[GroupBy[First -> Rest]]
```

the code takes about `0.4 seconds` to return the result.  But when I run

```
lst // GroupBy[{(#[[2]] &) -> (Drop[#, {2}] &), First -> Rest}]
```

the code takes about `five minutes` to return the result!

Is the second approach not recommended?  There is nothing in the official documentation to discourage its use, but it is about three orders of magnitude worse in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this has to do with the number of times you're changing the lengths of lists and the efficiency of `Map`. In general, I would discourage an approach that gradually reduces the lengths of lists. Your code uses `Drop`, `Rest` and `First` in sequence. It's probably more efficient to retain the sublists all through the calculation and only drop whatever you don't need at the end. Compare:

```
list = With[{n = 10000},
  Transpose@Join[
    RandomChoice[Alphabet[], {2, n}],
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, n}]
    ]
  ];

RepeatedTiming[
 list // GroupBy[(#[[2]] &) -> (Drop[#, {2}] &)] // 
   Map[GroupBy[First -> Rest]];]
```

with

```
Part[
 GroupBy[First] /@ GroupBy[list, #[[2]] &],
 All,
 All,
 All,
 {3, 4}
 ]; // RepeatedTiming
```

On my machine this runs a bit faster than your code. So instead of dropping elements while going through the calculation, just do it all at the end by using `Part` (which is a very efficient function).

Comment: I believe you are correct.  If I hold off on dropping the elements until the very end, the multiple `GroupBy` version runs as fast as the other version.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = With[{c = CharacterRange["a", "z"], r = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 20]},
  Flatten[{RandomChoice[c, {#, 2}], RandomChoice[r, {#, 2}]}, {{2}, {1, 3}}] &[150000]];
```

As a workaround you can use the 3rd argument of `GroupBy` which correspond to the functionality of `Map`:

```
a = lst // GroupBy[(#[[2]] &) -> (Drop[#, {2}] &)] // Map[GroupBy[First -> Rest]];
b = GroupBy[lst[[All, {2, 1, 3, 4}]], #, GroupBy[#]] &[First -> Rest];
a === b
```

> ```
> True
> ```